# jQuery countdown not showing up the expiration div

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

im doing a countdown in jquery and i have some problems with refreshing the countdwon.
Basically the countdown functions fine when refreshing the page if the the counter is expired it wont show the #counterlive div. It will stay at zero.

Am i missing something ? Im using the [countdown from here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var setDate = new Date();
        setDate.setFullYear(2013, 7-1, 18);
        setDate.setHours(15);
        setDate.setMinutes(00);
        setDate.setSeconds(0);

    $('#countdown').countdown({until: setDate,layout: '<div class=\"days\"><div id=\"day\">{d<}{dnn}{d>} </div><span id=\"days-span\">{dl}</span></div>' +
        '<div class=\"hours\"><div id=\"hours\">{h<}{hnn}{h>} </div><span id=\"hours-span\">{hl}</span></div>' + 
        '<div class=\"minutes\"><div id=\"minutes\">{m<}{mnn}{m>}</div><span id=\"minutes-span\">{ml}</span></div>' + 
        '<div class=\"seconds\"><div id=\"seconds\">{s<}{snn}{s>}</div><span id=\"seconds-span\">{sl}</span></div>',
        timezone: -5, // Set your time zone here. For more info (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)
        format: 'DHMS',
        onExpiry: liftOff
    });   

    function liftOff() { 

        $('#counter').hide();

        $('#counterlive').show();

    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like `liftOff()` isn't being called. Maybe put a `console.log("Working");` or something in there to see if it's even getting into that function. That would be my first step, then I'd go from there.

Comment: fixed the showing div as it was a class and not an id. However when refreshing the page the couterlive div wont stay on.

Comment: or better said if its running show the #counter, its it expired show the #couterlive